# Showing that 3 dimensional unit sphere is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $$\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3, x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$$

I need to show that this set is connected.

I have tough time handling connectedness.

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show that it is convex, hence path-connected.

Comment: @TomekKania A sphere is not convex. The ball is.

Comment: The confusion probably arises from the question title which uses the word "ball," but then asks about the unit sphere.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Name $S$ the sphere and $C$ the center of the sphere. Is its sufficient to prove that $S$ is path connected. Take two points $P_1 \neq P_2 \in S$. If $C, P_1, P_2$ lie on a line, any plane containing $(P_1,P_2)$ intersects $S$ as a circle. The "half-circle" from $P_1$ to $P_2$ joins $P_1$ to $P_2$ on the sphere.

And if $C, P_1, P_2$ are not lying on a line, the plane containing those 3 points again intersects the sphere $S$ in a circle. Either of the circle arcs joining $P_1$ to $P_2$ is a path on the sphere joining $P_1$ to $P_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "aligned"?

Comment: @tomasz It seems to mean "lie on a line".  The two cases could also be combined: it is in any case true that any plane passing through $C,P_1,P_2$ meets $S$ in a circle.

Comment: @Slade: I agree.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the English. It seems that are aligned cannot be used instead of lie on a line.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

The unit sphere $S^2$ is the image of the continuous map $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ sending $\vec{v}$ to $\frac{\vec{v}}{\|\vec{v}\|}$.

Since the continuous image of a connected set is connected, it is enough to show that $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ is connected.  But this is straightforward, as any two points can be connected by two lines.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ is not convex.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Indeed it isn't.